# Как избавиться от ошибки 404 в консоли при fetch()?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Есть асинхронный запрос с помощью fetch()

```js
fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=thereisnosuchacity&appid=secretid")
  .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp);  
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log("there is an error);
  });
```

При неправильном адресе консоль возвращает ошибку 404. Через try.. catch обработать никак, т.к. fetch() - асинхронный запрос, а метод .catch() не избавляет от ошибки в консоли:

GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=thereisnosuchacity&appid=081469d12d7f286e1ffbe66bbb381ce2 404 (Not Found)

Саму ошибку я отследить могу, нужно лишь, чтобы она не отображалась в консоли. Такое возможно?

Comment: Никак. Не нужно этого хотеть

Comment: Я уже понял, но все равно спасибо за ответ. Для тех, кто хочет узнать, зачем я спрашивал, я разрабатывал React.js веб-приложение по получению информации о погоде. Если ввести населенный пункт неправильно, то в консоли появляется ошибка 404. Я решил, что пока оставлю её так стоять, ну ничего страшного. https://first-simple-react-app.herokuapp.com/